# Entity Model Seperation and Constructor Logic

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

In our application, we do not use the EF Core entities directly, instead we map them onto corresponding "Model" classes, which in most cases look exactly the same, but implement INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Lets say i have a TimeSpan entity and a TimeSpanModel. Business logic dictates that a timespan is always a year, 1.1.xx to 31.12.xx. What i like to do to enforce this, is give the TimeSpanModel a constructor:

```
    public TimeSpanModel(int year)
    {
        From = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        To = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
    }
```

Im wondering, do i "need" to enforce the same thing on the actual entity? Entities only ever get created via repositories, which take Model instances as arguments.

I feel like i would double my logic, i'd have to remember to change it in 2 places.

But it also feels kind of "half measure". Its still possibly to create "wrong" timespan entites and persist them to the database. Its hard to solve without doubling the logic. The business layer is generally above the persistence layer, so i should not double the logic and just leave the entity be i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you share the EF model with some other app.

I recommend 2 layers.

A viewmodel matching however the data is presented.

A model which is whatever can be generated directly from the database and re-created simply if you change the database structure.

The viewmodel should have front end validation logic, data annotations and whatnot.

Your model doesn't need to know about any notifying of data errors to the UI. This is one of the things the viewmodel does.

If you had to share the model with some other app then you should consider putting dataannotations and the validation logic in a dto. Depending on how complicated that is and how you want to validate in the UI then you might only need those there.

Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo would be in the viewmodel in all cases.